# Github action jobs error when push branch is specified

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to trigger my pipeline on `develop` branch.

This code works :

```
name: develop

on: [push]
  jobs:
    build:

      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build Debug version
        run: |
            chmod +x pipelines.sh
            ./pipelines.sh "build"
```

This code does not works :

```
name: develop

on: 
  push:
    branches:    
      - 'develop'
  jobs:
    build:

      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build Debug version
        run: |
            chmod +x pipelines.sh
            ./pipelines.sh "build"
```

I have always this error message :

> jobs is not a valid event name

How must i format my file to make it works ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jobs` should be at the same level as `on` with no indentation.

```
on: 
  push:
    branches:    
      - 'develop'
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build Debug version
      run: |
          chmod +x pipelines.sh
          ./pipelines.sh "build"
```